# Is there an equivalent of mailto for Gmail?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, email, gmail, mailto

I am building a CMS for my company(using Rails 4, in case that matters) and nearly all of my users will be using Gmail.

Each user has a profile and I want it so when a user views another user's profile and clicks on their email address, Gmail will open with a new message to that user's email.

I imagine there'd be a way to do this using their API but so far I haven't found it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way I know of to specifically open Gmail; mailto always opens the default mail client, **which can be set to Gmail**.

See this guide (or direct your users to it) so that they can set Gmail as their default client: http://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/set-gmail-as-browser-default-email-client-ht